# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels** (or **440 x 500 pixels** [for high-resolution displays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247063/188148))
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5876).

Comment: ideas: 1) texample.net (?); 2) pgfmanual (??); 3) are there any good tex books freely available?

Comment: Hi Grace Note: Could you please confirm on the image specifications for community advt, is it `220 x 250 pixels`? or both `220 x 250 pixels or 440 x 500 pixels` see related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246442/high-res-community-advert and Links

Comment: @texenthusiast I went ahead and edited on the assumption of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247063/188148.

Answer (score 49):

[image: Detexify²]

Comment: This is a fantastic tool! Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

[image: TeX Live]

Answer (score 43):

[image: CTAN -- The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network]

Comment: The A-N kerning gets me, though.

Comment: It does look a tad tight, but this is the official logo.

Answer (score 38):

[image: TEXample.net]

Comment: I know it's not a sentence, but "examples resources for TeX users" seems incomplete. What about "examples & resource for TeX users"?

Comment: @Werner You are right, should be improved, I'll see when I can do it.

Answer (score 35):

[image: 2D and 3D Plots with LaTeX]

Answer (score 31):

[image: TeX Users Group]

Answer (score 25):

[image: Papeeria: free online collaborative LaTeX editor]

Answer (score 24):

[image: texdoc - TeX Documentation Tool in TeX Live]

Comment: I wish more people knew about this tool… didn't think to make it a community promotion ad! :)

Answer (score 22):

[image: arara -- The cool TEX automation tool]

Comment: The link leads to a site that does not explain very well why arara is as cool as it claims to be.  At least the site could be cooler: First, one has to scroll down to read about arara.  Second, the only example on the main page is that you can write `% arara: pdflatex` at the top of your file, and then arara will run `pdflatex` on your document.  That's not impressive...

Answer (score 21):

[image: Overleaf: Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with real-time PDF preview]

Answer (score 20):

[image: List of Tex Frequently Asked Questions on the Web]

Comment: This link appears to return a Not Found error.

Comment: @raxod502 Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 20):

[image: The Communications of the TeX Users Group]

Answer (score 20):

[image: MikTeX - a TeX distribution for Windows]

Comment: Logo was taken from [comunity-promotion-ads-2014](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/4061/1952). If a better one exists, fill free to replace it.

Answer (score 19):

[image: TeX.SX Meta]

Answer (score 19):

[image: ConTeXt User Wiki]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Using LaTeX to Write a Ph.D Thesis by Nicola Talbot]

Answer (score 18):

[image: DANTE e.v.]

Answer (score 18):

[image: TeXblog]

Comment: Continuing blogging in 2015 with new motivation. :-)

Answer (score 17):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/tex.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://tex.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: What was the fix to get this accepted?

Comment: @JosephWright: The system only wants an image at the creation of the answer. So I created the ad with a static picture and then edited it to have a dynamic image.

Comment: This is really neat!

Comment: It's just a copy of [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12383). :-)

Answer (score 15):

[image: Minimal Working Example(MWE)]

Comment: I don't think that this is very instructive.  My guess is that people will copy this preamble for their MWEs and still won't start to think about which packages are actually needed (Also this "MWE" doesn't make use of any of the packages).

Comment: @HenriMenke : I don't know if you have clicked on the advt it leads to the more detailed explanation and details of making an MWE clearly [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/15717). My example code of MWE is just a cut down example to accomodate in a small advt that shows widely used packages and commands to debug an error in LaTeX or make an MWE. you are free to add/modify the community wiki advt to add value and make it instructive. The final goal is to convey the idea of making an MWE to help in debugging LaTeX,thats all.

Comment: I am sorry but... the blue **MWE** is barely recognizable on the red background. I did click into it but that is because I can seldom see **What the Heck** on this site. This happened even before I saw **WME**. (If it is your purpose, ignore me...)

Comment: [here you are](http://imgur.com/LNQMNEZ).
MBPR, Yosemite, Chrome v40.

Comment: I did not see any of these ads today. (Instead I saw ads about questions on other .sx.) But [this](http://imgur.com/1yXtic1) is for your second requirement.

Comment: The example is _not_ a _minimal_ working example. It is only working!

Answer (score 14):

[image: CervanTeX - Spanish TeX Users Group]

Comment: CervanTeX is the spanish ("hispanohablantes") TeX user group

Comment: Would it be possible to make that clearer? Or would it be clear to Spanish speakers? i.e. to people who don't know the group but do understand Spanish?

Comment: @cfr Excuse me but I don't understand the question. CervanTeX is the Spanish TeX user group, just like Dante (with an  advertisement also in this list) or GuIT are for German and Italian. They have a web page with some information, a mail list, organize activities, membership, ... everything addressed to Spanish speakers/readers.

Comment: I just meant: would that be obvious from the ad? It is not obvious to me, but, then, I don't speak Spanish so that's irrelevant.

Comment: @cfr I understand. Probably you're right, it's not obvious from its logo. But an spanish speaker understand (or at least could be intrigued with) the mix between [Cervantes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miguel_de_Cervantes) and TeX.

Comment: IMHO one of the most clever ads I've ever seen. `:)` I'm so gonna write TeX code and tilt at windmills. `:)`

Comment: @cfr, The Don Quijote crazy idealism  linked with the creeping realism of Sancho Panza is not in our culture, but in our genome. Cervantes mean Spanish literature and way of being of Spaniards as well. The halberd as fountain pen and Sancho Panza as ... a inkwell (?) only reinforce the message.  What could be not clear about this logo for some Spanish speakers  is .... why Don Quijote is a kindly lion and what  the hell is TeX?

Answer (score 14):

[image: The LaTeX community is on Reddit!]

Comment: [Source published as a gist](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/39233f755386ab9e914c) – feel free to submit edits.  Image is exactly `440x500` pixels per the [MSE discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247063/188148).

Comment: I doubt majority of people know the reddit logo, maybe some text could be added.

Comment: @yo' Good point.  What do you think of the above? I'm unsure about having `/r/` be a new color, but it's what I had in a previous design (when `www.reddit.com` wasn't included).  What do you think?  Could either get rid of the darker blue of make `LaTeX` the same darker blue.  (The gist has been updated if you want to play around.)

Comment: This way it looks a bit like that `/r/` is of some significance, which is proobably not the case. But I'm not sure what would be better, so let's leave it be :)

Answer (score 13):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 13):

[image: A Persian Q&A site for TeX, LaTeX, and friends]

Comment: For a moment I thought that this was about writing nastaliq in TeX.

Comment: @WYSIWYG, Ha ha!

Answer (score 12):

[image: TeXworks editor - Lowering the entry barrier to the TeX world]

Comment: "The TeXworks project development has been generously supported by TUG’s TeX development fund and its contributors, and by UK-TUG to lower the entry barrier to the TeX world"

Answer (score 11):

[image: LaTeX Community]

Answer (score 10):

[image: comp.text.tex]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Tex.SE Community Blog]

Comment: To promote a blog that have not been updated for 3 months (and if one ignores a congratulation post — for **7 months**) seems strange

Comment: @GrigoryM: Now there is a new post. :-)

Answer (score 7):

[image: ShareLaTeX, online editor]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Just copying from the [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/4025/52417)